# Unknown Betamax film from 80s?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, soft-sci-fi

I'm trying to remember the name of a feature scifi cartoon. I can't remember much about the film but I think the main character was a boy called Orion. There was a scene set in a sort of desert with cyborgs that would capture humans in order to take their organs and limbs to make themselves more human.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/mid-1980s-animated-theatrical-release

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [Starchaser: The Legend of Orin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starchaser:_The_Legend_of_Orin), a 1985 animated sci-fi adventure film. The main character is named Orin, not Orion, but the rest fits.

> In the future on a planet named Trinia, human slaves have lived underground for millennia mining crystals for a "god" named Zygon and his robot minions. One day Orin, a young miner, finds a jeweled sword embedded in the rocks. Hopps, grandfather of Orin's girlfriend Elan, recognizes the sword and gives his life to save Orin and keep the sword a secret.
>
> [...]
>
> Orin digs a tunnel to the surface of Trinia, where he is later captured by Man-Droids, a group of decaying half-organic, half-robotic beings who intend to tear him apart and use his body parts to replace their own.

[image]

(I found this by Googling "sci-fi cartoon orion".)

Comment: Best 3D movie ever made?  Wow.

Comment: that is a bold claim