# Cyborgs chasing humans for parts

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I am not exactly sure of the year I saw it. I rented it from Blockbuster Video somewhere between the late 1990s to the early 2000s. (?)

What I remember is that it was a hand-drawn animated film. One part of the film that really sticks in my mind is a scene where a number of half human, half machines (discarded?) were digging through a pile of parts/trash to re-fit themselves. They are being observed by a couple of humans who I think had made an emergency landing on this planet. (?) All of a sudden, they are discovered by the cyborgs and the cyborgs realize that the humans are a ready supply of their damaged human parts and give chase. I especially remember the next line from one of the cyborgs, "I will wear his feet!" I recently bought a book of animated movies but the only movie description that comes close is "Titan A. E."

Comment: I wonder if this movie influenced *A.I.: Aritificial Intelligence*. The cyborgs digging in a pile of parts is reminiscent of *A.I*.

Comment: Can you speak to the style of animation? Such as Anime / Japanese, vs more US looking stuff?

Comment: I only saw it once and so long ago . I was leaning more toward the Japanese style animation until I read an answer posted by IMDB with a collage of images from the movie " Starchaser : The Legend of Orin " . The animation stills in the collage seem to have a more American style to them . They also look familiar . IMDB also includes a quote from the actual screenplay that ends with " I will wear his feet ! " This seems to be irrefutable evidence that points to Starchaser , however , I will buy the film and watch it to dispel any doubt .

Answer (score 3):

Could it be Starchaser: The Legend of Orin?

[image]

> Set on the subterranean Mine-World, a band of human worker are treated like slaves under the power of the evil overlord Zygon until one, Orin, unearths the hilt of a mythical sword that only he can master. Escaping the planet, he runs into the rogue smuggler Dagg and a pair of helpful droids and the princess, who all team up to return to the Mine-World with a plan to defeat Zygon and free Orin's enslaved people. - [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090065/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

The [screenplay](http://www.jeffreyscott.tv/starchaser.pdf) (as posted by the author Jeffrey Scott on his website) has the mentioned line.

> Two more mandroids block his path. Orin runs the other way.
>
> BORO (CONT’D)
>   He killed everyone. He's dangerous.
>   FREG
>   Dangerous? Ha! **I'll wear his feet.**
>
> Freg and the other mandroid run off after Orin.

Here is a bizarre collage of images.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the bizarre collage of images. If this does turn out to be the answer, it's a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/mid-1980s-animated-theatrical-release